# Which data types does tf use?

Tags: ros, geometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know what datatypes tf can work with natively.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9040/which-data-types-does-tf-use?/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the tf wiki page on [tf/data types](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/data%20types)

[tf](http://ros.org/wiki/tf) can be used either with the underlying Bullet transform types or with the transform types available in the geometry_msgs package. Since tf deals with coordinate frames, every datatype that tf uses needs to be stamped, i.e. extra information is added to the datatype to represent the name of the frame in which it lives and a timestamp. The timestamp typically represents the time at which the data was created/ last valid.

tf can directly operate on the following messages or Bullet datatypes:

- Pose - tf can transform poses by using the [tf::transformPose](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html#502cbf4e7d4aa2ad822c830629957bdf/) function. The transformPose function can operate on:
- [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PointStamped.html) - A stamped representation of a pose expressed in a particular frame
- `tf::Stamped<tf::Pose>` - A templated stamped representation of the underlying Bullet datatype btTransform.
- Position - tf can transform positions (or points) using the [tf::transformPoint](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html#502cbf4e7d4aa2ad822c830629957bdf/) function. The transformPoint function can operate on:
- [geometry_msgs/PointStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PointStamped.html) - Represents a stamped point in 3D.
- `tf::Stamped<tf::Point>` - A stamped version of the underlying Bullet datatype [btVector3](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtVector3.html).
- Rotation - tf can transform a rotation using the [tf::transformQuaternion](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html#502cbf4e7d4aa2ad822c830629957bdf/) function. The transformQuaternion function can operate on:
- [geometry_msgs/QuaternionStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/QuaternionStamped.html) - A stamped representation of a quaternion.
- `tf::Stamped<tf::Quaternion>` - A stamped version of the underlying Bullet datatype [btQuaternion](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtQuaternion.html).
- Vector - tf can transform a free vector using the [tf::transformVector](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html#502cbf4e7d4aa2ad822c830629957bdf/) function. The tranformVector function can operate on:
- [geometry_msgs/VectorStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/VectorStamped.html) - A stamped representation of a free vector.
- `tf::Stamped<tf::Vector3>` - A stamped version of the underlying Bullet datatype [btVector](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtVector3.html).
- PointCloud - tf can transform point clouds directly using the [tf::transformPointCloud](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html#502cbf4e7d4aa2ad822c830629957bdf/) function. This function operates on:
- [sensor_msgs/PointCloud](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html) - A representation of a 3D point cloud.

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-28**:
Wow!! , the 1st question on Ros answers (: